# replace last delimeter with "and" in a string in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I want to replace last delimeter (comma) with **and**  in a string in SSRS 2008 R2.
if there are more than one product, and the cost of products are different, then the product of each must must be listed separated by commas and ‘and’ before the last one.

i.e.,
Input string- Hi,Hello,HRU,

Desired output- Hi,Hello and  HRU..

how can I achieve this (and before last word) ?

(suggest in SSRS or even in SQL)

Rgds/-

Comment: Your input ends in a comma, is this intentional? Also, the output ends in two full stops... Is this the intended output?

Answer (score 0):

I would put a code element to the report as follows:

lblSomething=Code.DoSomething(string)

And your custom code, Code.DoSomething ,code could check for the conditions you have listed above.

ThANKS